# M2MQTT in Portable Class Library

Tags: wpf, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, portable-class-library, uwp

I would like to share my M2MQTT code between a Windows 10 universal windows platform application and a windows phone 8.1 application. Perhaps a WPF app in the future.

I've attempted to use NuGet to include M2MQTT in a portable class library (PCL). I targeted the PCL with a minimum of requirements to satisfy both project types. I receive the following error. Is it possible to reference m2mqtt in a portable class library that can be shared by both UWP and WP8.1 projects?

```
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'M2Mqtt.4.2.0.1' with respect to project 'Pcl45', targeting '.NETPortable,Version=v4.6,Profile=Profile32'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'M2Mqtt.4.2.0.1' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'M2Mqtt.4.2.0.1'
Resolved actions to install package 'M2Mqtt.4.2.0.1'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'M2Mqtt 4.2.0.1' does not exist in project 'Pcl45'
Could not install package 'M2Mqtt 4.2.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.6,Profile=Profile32', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

**Additional Information 9/24/2015**

I cloned the [M2MQTT GitHub repository](https://github.com/ppatierno/m2mqtt) and noticed that there is a .pcl for Windows 8.1 and Windows phone 8.1. I didn't see support for UWP in a .pcl though.

I suppose I have my answer. No M2MQTT does not support .pcl in UWP projects.

Wondering if there are any plans to add .pcl support in the future?

Also if I might be able to use M2MQTT in Xamarin Android or Ios projects?

**Additional Information 9/28/2015**
Following suggestions from @Anders Gustafsson I successfully created a .pcl that I was able to consume in my UWP app and windows phone 8.1 app. No more duplication of code. Nice. Hope this will work in xamarin android and ios.

There is this warning.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Source Warning
Some NuGet packages were installed using a target framework different from 
the current target framework and may need to be reinstalled. Visit 
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages for more 
information.  Packages affected: M2Mqtt Pcl45       0   Build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*M2MQTT* is available as a PCL profile 32 assembly, which is capable of targeting Windows 8.1, Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 10/UWP projects. The *M2Mqtt.WinRT* assembly is really a PCL Profile 32 assembly.

The problem you are facing is that this fact is not reflected in the *NuGet* package. In the *NuGet* package there are separate *lib* folders for *win81* and *wpa81* with the *M2Mqtt.WinRT* assembly in both. The desirable scenario would have been that there should have been a single sub-folder *portable-win81+wpa81* containing the *M2Mqtt.WinRT*, then everything would (probably) have worked flawlessly for you.

There seems to be one workaround, although I cannot promise that it is fully reliable.

- Start off creating a portable class library, but set the only target for the PCL to *Windows 8.1*. (If that does not work immediately, create a PCL that targets *Windows 8.1* and *Windows Phone 8.1*, and when the PCL has been created, uncheck the *Windows Phone 8.1* check box.)
- Add the *M2MQTT* package from NuGet to your PCL. Your PCL will now reference the *M2Mqtt.WinRT* assembly in the *win81* sub-folder.
- Add *Windows Phone 8.1* as a target of your PCL, so that your PCL (again) targets both *Windows 8.1* and *Windows Phone 8.1*. You may receive warning messages from NuGet when doing this; ignore those messages.

Now, you should be able to consume the *M2Mqtt.WinRT* assembly from your PCL, and you should also be able to reference your PCL in a UWP application.

To add more reliability once you have managed to download the *M2MQTT* package from NuGet, you might manually delete and then re-add the reference to the *M2Mqtt.WinRT* assembly in your PCL project. That way you will short-circuit NuGet, preventing NuGet from accidentally trying to restore your *M2Mqtt.WinRT* reference from a non-existing (*portable-win81+wpa81*) directory.

Comment: Cool! It worked. There is a warning in my .pcl (that I tried to inline code in this comment, I can't seem to introduce a newline??. I'll add in my original post)

Comment: Good to hear that it worked out for you. I have also posted [an issue](https://github.com/ppatierno/m2mqtt/issues/4) on Github so that eventually the M2MQTT maintainers can solve the problem more permanently. Regarding *iOS* and *Android*; PCL Profile 32 is specialized towards modern Windows, and is **not** compatible with *iOS* and *Android*. I have not tried it, but maybe the .NET source code is general enough to be compilable for *iOS* and *Android* as well?

Answer (score 0):

I cloned the M2MQTT GitHub repository and noticed that there is a .pcl for Windows 8.1 and Windows phone 8.1. I didn't see support for UWP in a .pcl though.

I suppose I have my answer. No. M2MQTT does not currently support .pcl in UWP projects.

Comment: See @anders-gustafsson answer for a workaround that worked for me.